# Highlight polyline route when clicking on it (Google Maps v3)

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a lot of routes on my map and I would like to highlight a route when I click on it. Well, actually I click on a stop-marker = last position in route. This is my code:

```
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions); // need this as global variable (used outside this $(document)

  // Get all trips within selected timespan
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    url: "data.json"
  }).done(function(jsonRoutes) {

    var lastLatLng = null; // needed for placing a marker on the last stop-position

    // Define an "InfoWindow" for clicking on the stop-position marker
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });

    // Click anywhere on the map to close the info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,"click",function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });

    // Get all routes from a JSON query
    $.each(jsonRoutes, function(key,obj) {

      coordinatesRoute = []; // clear/set an array holding all coordinates

      var data = obj.data; // object which contains all JSON data

      // Walk through each position in the route
      $.each(data, function(key,obj) {
        var lat = obj.lat;
        var lng = obj.lng;

        // Push actual coordinate to both coordinate arrays
        coordinatesRoute.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
        coordinatesAll.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));

        lastLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); // store the last position
      });

      // Draw the polyline route (the whole route)
      var polylinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: coordinatesRoute,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      polylinePath.setMap(map);

       // Insert a "stop-position" marker (last position in route)
      var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("icon.png",null,null,new google.maps.Point(0,8));
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: lastLatLng,
        title: "Stop",
        map: map,
        zIndex: 5000,
        icon: icon
      });

      // Click on a "stop-position" marker to open an info window
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function() {
        infowindow.open(map,this);
        infowindow.setContent(this.title);
      });

    }); // $.each(jsonRoutes, function(key,obj)

    // Auto center/zoom map to show all routes
    // Source: http://blog.shamess.info/2009/09/29/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-maps-api-v3/
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // create a new viewpoint bound
    for(var i = 0, LtLgLen = coordinatesAll.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
      bounds.extend (coordinatesAll[i]); // increase the bounds to take this point
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  }); // $.ajax

} // initialize()
```

Can anyone help me out what I need to be able to highlight any route I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean exactly with 'highlight' the route... If it is just to change the color than you can do something like:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            polylinePath.setOptions({strokeColor: '#00FFaa'});
            infowindow.open(map,this);
            infowindow.setContent(this.title);
        });
```

but doing it color will be fixed to the new value.

You can change the color property on mouseover/mouseout event, for example:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(polylinePath, 'mouseover', function(latlng) {
            polylinePath.setOptions({strokeColor: '#00FFAA'});
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(polylinePath, 'mouseout', function(latlng) {
            polylinePath.setOptions({strokeColor: '#FF0000'});
        });
```

so path color will be set back to initial one.

**Update:** If you want to switch off previously highlighted polyline you can do something like this: add global variable which hold polyline which is highlighted:

```
var highlightedPoly;
```

and change event listener to:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            if (highlightedPoly) {
                highlightedPoly.setOptions({strokeColor: '#FF0000'});
            }

            polylinePath.setOptions({strokeColor: '#00FFaa'});
            highlightedPoly = polylinePath;

            infowindow.open(map,this);
            infowindow.setContent(this.title);
        });
```

Map click event listener could be expanded in similar way:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
        infowindow.close();

        if (highlightedPoly) {
            highlightedPoly.setOptions({strokeColor: '#FF0000'});
        }        
    });
```

Comment: This is great but is there any way that when a route is highlighted (when clicked on a marker) that it then could set the color back to normal when I click somewhere else on the map?

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted - thanks a lot. I will update my question a little so it is more precise for future readers.

Comment: Maybe I should add a new question but this is related to the exact same code - do you also know how I can add individual infowindows to to each route? I have more info available (e.g. time it took) and I would like to display this on each route but I only seem to be able to show the same text on all routes if I use a variable.

Comment: That depends on your design. People use different approaches: hard coded info, databases... you can check other questions connected with infowindows.